# In python apache beam, is it possible to write elements in a specific order?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using beam to process time series data over overlapping windows. At the end of my pipeline I am writing each element to a file. Each element represents a csv row and one of the fields is a timestamp of the associated window. I would like to write the elements in order of that timestamp. Is there a way to do this using the python beam library?

Comment: It sounds like you're also writing a file per window.  Is that correct, or can you write multiple files per window?

Comment: No, I'm not writing a file per window. It's one csv file, and each window computation will be a row on that file.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that your pipeline has a single output file?

Comment: yup, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't part of the base distribution, this is something you could implement by processing these elements and sorting them as part of a global window before writing out to a file, with the following caveats:

- The entire contents of the window would need to fit in memory, or you would need to chunk up the file into smaller global windows.
- If you are doing the second option, you'd need to have a strategy for writing the smaller windows in order to the file.